# How do I enter a number and count in sequence 10 numbers higher using a for loop

Tags: c, for-loop

How can I get a user to input a number then the program increments the users number by 10?

for example the user enters 5 the number 5 increments like this 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 
15

This is my code so far.

```
int main (void)
{

    int i;

    for(i=1; i<10; i++);
    {
         printf("enter a number:");
         scanf("%d" , &i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should probably scan in the number before beginning the loop ;)

Comment: What you've got now will ask the user for 10 numbers. Move that before the loop so that you're only asking for a single number. Also your loop goes from 1 to 9 (`i<10`) so either start `i` at 0 or check for `i<=10`. Also, you're not incrementing the number provided... You might want a good book or some tutorials on coding

Comment: this post is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13268837/in-c-how-do-i-enter-a-number-then-get-that-value-and-make-it-count-10-numbers-on/13269539#13269539

Answer (score 2):

You can use two variables:

- `start`: the first index of the loop;
- `end`: the last index of the loop.

Then, the program is quite easy to write:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int start;
int end;   

scanf("%d", &start);

end = start + 10;

for (i = start; i < end; ++i)
    printf("%d\n", i);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int main (void)
{      
     printf("enter a number:");

     int num;
     scanf("%d", &num);
     for (int i = num; i <= num + 10; i++) 
     { 
            printf("%d ", i);
     }

     printf("\n");

     return 0;
}
```

Comment: The program needs a user input

Comment: @KerryWarnes I believe Petar thought you would be capable of addressing that aspect and that you were not expecting a full program to be delivered to you on a platter. His edit to provide that is very nice but you should realize SO is a place to help you learn, not a free contracting service.

Comment: I'm not expecting to have it spoon fed to me I have been playing around with this code for the last three hours I just need some help

Comment: May I ask Peter why are there 2 for loops.

Comment: The first loop is if you wanna do the same operation more than one time. If you want it only one time, feel free to remove the outer loop(with the i variable).

Answer (score 0):

```
int main (void) {
  int start;

  printf("enter a number:");
  scanf("%d" , &start);

  for(int i=0; i<=10; i++) {
    printf("%d",start+i);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Will this work? There were a number of syntax errors that I believe I corrected. If you have questions on what I changed please comment and I'll be happy to help!

Comment: You're not declaring i, and you're starting i late (adding 1 to it prematurely) and hence stopping the loop one too late also (based on the question's requirements).

Answer (score 0):

Make a `while` loop. First set the counter `i` to 0, the result of the`i` and `number` sum will be stored in result, and this will happen every time the while loop restarts, the first time will be `number + 1` (6) (cause `i` is 1), `then number + 2` (7), `number + 3` (8), . . ., `number + 10` (15).

PD: number is never changed, it stays with the same value you entered.

```
int main (void)
{
   int i, number, result;

   printf( "Enter the number: " );
   scanf( "%d", &number );


   i = 0;
   while ( result != ( number + 10 ) )
      printf( "%d", result = number + i );
      i++;  
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{    
    int i,n;

    printf("enter a number:");
    scanf("%d" , &n);

    for(i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
       printf("%d ",n);
       ++n;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That'll print n..n but the OP wanted n..(n+10)

Comment: If the number being input is 5, and the desired output is 5 6 7 ... (as presented in the question), do you think this solution achieves that?

Comment: @mah Yes, the solution achieves that, where did I increment it twice?

Comment: Sorry, I misread the i++ and ++n; only one increment. A strange solution (a little more complicated than it needs to be), but I'll delete my prior comment.